# Does anyone recognize this math font? I don't know if it's even still around, it's from one of Einstein's papers on General Relativity

Tags: math-mode, fonts, physics

[image]

[image]

Sorry if the images don't look the best.

Comment: if you gave a proper citation then someone would probably know what font the journal used rather than recognise it by eye, (not that a box of metal characters would help much in TeX)

Comment: It looks like [The Principle of Relativity, a collection of original memoirs on the special and general theory of relativity, by H.A. Lorentz, A. Einstein, H. Minkowski and H. Weyl, Dover Publications, 1952](https://books.google.nl/books?id=S1dmLWLhdqAC&lpg=PA122&ots=gEUxD1PlZN&pg=PA122#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: maybe "Old Times American Heavy"!!

Comment: See [this post](https://superuser.com/a/17773/1073810).

Comment: In my humble opinion, those symbols you are looking for do not exist in LaTeX or TeX; you can find something here that is similar to them: https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/mathfonts.html

Comment: Old Times American Heavy is the right font for the normal text, but is there something that looks like that with math support?

Comment: Here is the source: http://hermes.ffn.ub.es/luisnavarro/nuevo_maletin/Einstein_GRelativity_1916.pdf